# Is MessageConsumer.completionHandler necessary for EventBus.localConsumer?

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx-eventbus

The following code could be part of a custom *request/response* implementation. I am not using [`EventBus.request`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/eventbus/EventBus.html#request-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-io.vertx.core.Handler-) because I need a bit more freedom like sending multiple responses to a single request.

```
String replyAddress = generateUniqueAddress();
replyConsumer = eventBus.localConsumer(replyAddress, this::handleReply);
replyConsumer.completionHandler(result -> {
  if (result.succeeded()) {
    eventBus.send("someAddress", new SomeMessageWhichContainsMyReplyAddress(replyAddress));
  }
  else {
    ...
  }
});
```

The question: Do I actually have to wait for the completion handler or can I simplify the code like this?

```
String replyAddress = generateUniqueAddress();
replyConsumer = eventBus.localConsumer(replyAddress, this::handleReply);
eventBus.send("someAddress", new SomeMessageWhichContainsMyReplyAddress(replyAddress));
```

The Javadoc of [`MessageConsumer.completionHandler`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/eventbus/MessageConsumer.html#completionHandler-io.vertx.core.Handler-) describes that this method notifies the given handler *“when the registration has been propagated across the cluster”*. Since there is no cluster with [`EventBus.localConsumer`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/eventbus/EventBus.html#localConsumer-java.lang.String-io.vertx.core.Handler-), is it valid to assume that the registration is always propagated on the local event bus immediately? I checked the implementation of *Vert.x 3.9.3* and at least for this version, the registration seems to be synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Completion handler is called exactly once, after your listener registers. If you want to send a message to `someAddress` once that happens, then your initial code is correct.

Your second example will be inconsistent, due to Vert.x asynchronous nature. Most probably when you send the message, your local consumer won't be registered yet, and the message lost as a result.

If your intention is to send a new message to `someAddress` after each new message received, then both pieces of code are wrong.

Comment: *“If your intention is to send a new message to someAddress after each new message received, then both pieces of code are wrong.”* – It is not my intention. I changed the example a bit in order to make it more clear.

Comment: I checked the implementation of Vert.x 3.9.3, where it seems to be synchronous. So you are saying I cannot relay on the registration being synchronous and should rather treat it as an implementation detail of Vert.x?